# Are these mushrooms still edible?

Tags: food-safety, mushrooms

Are these mushrooms still edible? The colour of the gills changed.

I'm not sure what kind of mushrooms they are. They're not store-bought though, my mother picked them from the forest. She also washed them straight away. They've been stored in the refrigerator for 5 days. No off-odour. Gill's colour changed from light brown to dark brown-black.

[image: mushrooms]

Comment: What kind of mushroom are they, how were they stored and how long?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of mushrooms they are. They're not store-bought though, my mother picked them from the forest. She also washed them straight away. They've been stored in the refrigerator for 5 days. No off-odour. Gills's colour changed from light brown to dark brown-black.

Comment: I would think this is unanswerable.  Wild collected mushrooms of unknown variety regardless of how they are stored or their condition cannot honestly be called safe from a picture.  This is a high risk item without the facts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are Agaricus campestris L
https://manatarka.org/agaricus-campestris/

Comment: Gill darkening is pretty normal over time. Slimey feel, dry spots and other fungi growing on your shrooms are the big danger signs.

Comment: All mushrooms are edible, some only once... In all seriousness, if you don't EXACLTY how to identify a Deathcap, don't pick and eat wild mushrooms. This advice may vary with location (for example, eating wild mushrooms is common in some parts of Asia known not to have the dangerous varieties--but even then, how do you know some evil American hasn't smuggled some in?)

Answer (score 10):

**No - not edible**, is the only responsible answer to this question. From the given information and photo, it's impossible for someone on these message boards to positively identify what you have.

The saying is "*When in doubt, throw it out*". As with all foraged mushrooms, don't eat it if you are not able to 100% positively identify it. This goes for fresh and as well as 5-day refrigerated specimens.

*My background: 3 years experience foraging local wild fungi in midwestern USA and scientific fungi identification.*